# matlab add images of different widths

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How can I add two images in matlab with different widths? (stitch them together).

```
Img3 = imadd(Img1, Img2_new);
```

does not work. It requieres same munber of rows and columns..

B image is wider that A image.
Here is the result I want get:
[image]

Ideal will be if I can change size of bounding box of image A (add more black part) and then imadd will work

Thanks

Comment: What do you _want_ to happen? If you have small image of a circle and a large image of a house, do you want the final image to be a house in a circle? Size of the image of the house? Or size of the image of the circle? Do you want a little circle in the corner of the image of the house? Centered? See why Matlab doesn't let you "just" sum two different sized images? It can't read your mind. Specify more carefully and we can help you. Or do you mean "stitch" as in put them side by side? The latter is just `image3 = [img1 img2_new];` - horizontal concatenation.

Comment: @Floris you almost got it right, I can see some buildings there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what you mean by "stitching". Usually that would mean concatenating - horizontally or vertically. If images are not the same size, it is not immediately obvious how to concatenate.

The simplest thing to do would be to rescale the two images (A,B) to be the same size - below an example of doing that (making B the size of A, then adding):

```
Br = imresize(B,size(A));
C = imadd(A,Br);
```

If you mean "concatenate", then you would use

```
C = [A Br];
```

to put images size by side, or

```
C = [A; Br];
```

to put A on top of B

**edit** now you showed what you really want! the solution is

```
C=B;
r=size(A,1); c=size(A,2);
C(1:r,1:c) = C(1:r,1:c)+A;
```

Or if you want to use `imadd`:

```
Ab = zeros(size(B));
r=size(A,1); c=size(A,2);
Ab(1:r,1:c) = Ab(1:r,1:c)+A;
C=imadd(Ab,B);
```

Comment: I do not want scale the image. Concatenating is also not my case. Because images has overlapping part. See my edits in post. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. Just one thing: I wrote 'C(1:r, 1:c, 1:3) = C(1:r, 1:c, 1:3) + A(1:r, 1:c, 1:3)'; to keep color info correct. Otherwise non-overlapped parts have wrong color (color is still from image B, but should be from A)

Comment: Ah - you have color images. The picture suggested it was grayscale... Glad it worked!